# How to use os.rename to move a file with an uncertain name?

Tags: python-3.x, filesystems, wildcard, directory-structure, file-rename

My python script downloads .pdf files but they have dynamically generated names, so I rename and move them to the folders that I work with them in.
But from what I understand python doesn't support the equivalent of a wild-card
so that is why I guess this code doesn't work.

```
os.rename('downloads/*.pdf','outputs/' + jpm + '/' + jpm + '-oa.pdf')
```

I also used shutil.move and it gave me a similar error to the one i will show you but it only complained about the source directory the os.rename complained about the entire line.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'downloads/*.pdf' -> 'outputs/JPM0522733/JPM0522733-oa.pdf'
```

So how can I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module glob implements the equivalent of a wild-card. You can make a list of your downloaded files, like so

```
import glob
dfiles = glob.glob1('downloads','*.pdf')
```

So as to get sure that you rename the downloaded files differently, you can then create a list whose length is equal to `len(dfiles)` so as to associate a new name to each of those.

```
jpm = 'JPM0522733'
nfiles = map(lambda i: '{0}-{1}oa.pdf'.format(jpm,i), 
             ['']+list(range(len(dfiles)))
         )
```

Note that there is no need to turn the range into a list if you are under python<3, which *a contrario* will cause a `can only concatenate list (not "range") to list` error under python3+.

and finally loop over the two lists, considered in parallel, to rename each pdf file

```
for dfile,nfile in zip(dfiles,nfiles):
    os.rename( 
        os.path.join('downloads', dfile),
        os.path.join('outputs', jpm, nfile)
    )
```

Assuming that the folders whose names are `"downloads"`, `"outputs"` and `jpm` do exist. If not you will need to create them.

Comment: Thank you for responding.
I currently am haveing this error.
[''] + range(len(dfiles))
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "range") to list

Comment: @Gdfelt. Ok this is possible with python27 but not with python3 apparently.  The error is due to the line `['']+range(len(dfiles))`. I learnt something new. See my update. Juste replace the line by `['']+list(range(len(dfiles)))`

Comment: Worked like a charm!
Thank you very much.